# Convergent subsequences with the same limits imply a convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that the sequences $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$
converge to limits $a$ and $b$ in the real numbers $R$ respectively.

Show that $a = b$ if and only if $(a_n)$ is convergent.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the left to right side: Pick $N$ so that $ | a_{2n}-a|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. Then, pick $M$ so that $ | a_{2n+1}-b|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>M$. Pick $N^*=\max\{N, M\}$. Since $a=b$ then, $ | a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>2N^*$.

For the right to left side: a convergent series only converges to a single point, hence $a=b$.

Comment: why is it n>2N*?

Comment: because $N$ and $M$ were chosen for $a_{2n(+1)}$, not $a_n$, so you have to pick $2N^*$ to compensate